# Is it possible to combine these 2 linq queries?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I'm using entity framework to return my data.

I have 2 almost identical methods/queries. The only difference is that one has an additional Where statement.

The first query gets the average value of accepted transactions, and the second query gets the average of all transactions.

Here are the 2 methods:

```
    static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetBuyerEPA()
    {
        var collectTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayEnd();
        var collectFrom = collectTo.AddDays(-29).DayStart();

        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
        {
            var r = new Repository<MatchHistory>(uow.Context);

            return r.Find()
                .Where(x =>
                    x.ResultTypeId == (int)MatchResultType.Accepted &&
                    x.CreatedOn <= collectTo &&
                    x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom)
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.BuyerId,
                    x.TreeId,
                    x.TierId
                })
                .ToList()
                .Select(x => new BuyerEarning(
                    x.Key.BuyerId,
                    x.Key.TreeId,
                    x.Key.TierId,
                    x.Average(y => y.Commission)))
                .ToList();
        }
    }

    static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetBuyerEPL()
    {
        var collectTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayEnd();
        var collectFrom = collectTo.AddDays(-29).DayStart();

        using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
        {
            var r = new Repository<MatchHistory>(uow.Context);

            return r.Find()
                .Where(x =>
                    x.CreatedOn <= collectTo &&
                    x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom)
                .GroupBy(x => new
                {
                    x.BuyerId,
                    x.TreeId,
                    x.TierId
                })
                .ToList()
                .Select(x => new BuyerEarning(
                    x.Key.BuyerId,
                    x.Key.TreeId,
                    x.Key.TierId,
                    x.Average(y => y.Commission)))
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Rather than have 2 distinct queries I'd like to use 1 that returns BuyerId, TreeId, TierId, EpaValue, EplValue. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: I don't see any `EpaValue` property in any query

Comment: Couldn't you use an `||` (OR) in your where statement to combine the two?

Comment: What are `EpaValue` and `EplValue`?  They're not mentioned in your code.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky - there is a property in each query labelled 'Value'. If the 2 queryies were combined I would need 2 new properties to hold bothe values.

Comment: @RoadieRich - please see my answer to lazybereovsky

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While most of the other answers are showing you how to use the same code to toggle the query between EPL and EPA, I believe what you are asking is how to get both values in a single query.

```
static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetBuyerEPA()
{
    var collectTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayEnd();
    var collectFrom = collectTo.AddDays(-29).DayStart();

    using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
    {
        var r = new Repository<MatchHistory>(uow.Context);

        return r.Find()
            .Where(x =>
                x.CreatedOn <= collectTo &&
                x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom)
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.BuyerId,
                x.TreeId,
                x.TierId
            })
            .Select(x => new BuyerEarning(
                x.Key.BuyerId,
                x.Key.TreeId,
                x.Key.TierId,
                x.Average(y => y.Commission), //EPL
                x.Where(y => y.ResultTypeId == (int)MatchResultType.Accepted)
                    .Average(y => y.Commission)) //EPA
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Though it may depend on how the SQL query is generated, I think you can get rid of the first `.ToList()` (yes, I know that's how his query looks, but that still doesn't mean it isn't superfluous).

Comment: Good call, I copied and pasted that from the question and I didn't even notice it was there.

Comment: @Tory - can't get rid of the ToList() - link to entities doesn't support

Comment: @cadrell0 - correct - I'm looking to return values together rather than individually. ToList() is needed as Linq to entities only supports parameterless constructors. Thanks

Comment: @dotnetnoob - Doesn't support what? (You left out the object of that sentence)  LINQ to Entities should be able to go from a `.Groupby(...)` to a `.Select(...)` just fine without a `.ToList()` in between them.

Comment: @Tory - only supports parameterless constructors  - Can't create BuyerEarning need new BuyerEarning { BuyerId = x.Key.BuyerId, etc. } or ToList()

Comment: @dotnetnoob - Ah.  But that is only true for the Auto-generated Entities themselves (which can only be safely generated by the code to have parameter-less constructors).  If you have a normal class in which you are placing the data into, then you can use constructors with parameters - even in the IQueriable context.

Comment: @Tory - if you remove the ToList(), the query will cause a runtime error

Comment: Strange.  I'm able to do that just fine.  The only thing I can think of is: Do you have an Entity named BuyerEarning and a local class also named BuyerEarning?  But that shouldn't work as that should cause an ambiguity error.  I can't replicate it, so I have no idea why it works for me and not you.

Answer (score 3):

You can create helper method with a predicate as parameter:

```
static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetXXXX(Func<MatchHistory, bool> predicate = null)
{
    var collectTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayEnd();
    var collectFrom = collectTo.AddDays(-29).DayStart();

    using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
    {
        var r = new Repository<MatchHistory>(uow.Context);

        var filtered = r.Find()
                        .Where(x.CreatedOn <= collectTo && x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom);

        if(predicate != null)
            filtered = filtered.Where(predicate);

        return filtered 
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.BuyerId,
                x.TreeId,
                x.TierId
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new BuyerEarning(
                x.Key.BuyerId,
                x.Key.TreeId,
                x.Key.TierId,
                x.Average(y => y.Commission)))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

And then use it within each of the original methods:

```
static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetBuyerEPA()
{
    return GetXXXX(x => x.ResultTypeId == (int)MatchResultType.Accepted);
}

static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetBuyerEPL()
{
    return GetXXXX();
}
```

***Btw.***, why do you use `ToList()` before final projection? It makes the `Average` calculation being performed by application (using LINQ to Objects), which is much less efficient then when done by SQL Server.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `Expression<Func<MatchHistory, bool>>`?

Comment: Using linq to entities which only supprts parameterless constructors

Answer (score 3):

Why not refactor the `Where` clause and pass it in as a variable?

```
var epaFilter = new Func<MatchHistory, bool>(x => x.ResultTypeId == (int)MatchResultType.Accepted &&      x.CreatedOn <= collectTo &&                    x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom);
var eplFilter = new Func<MatchHistory, bool>(x => x.CreatedOn <= collectTo && x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom);        

private static IEnumerable<MatchHistory> GetBuyerByFilter(Func<MatchHistory,Boolean> filter)
{
    var collectTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayEnd();
    var collectFrom = collectTo.AddDays(-29).DayStart();

    using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
    {
        var r = new Repository<MatchHistory>(uow.Context);

        return r.Find()
            .Where(filter)
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.BuyerId,
                x.TreeId,
                x.TierId
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new BuyerEarning(
                x.Key.BuyerId,
                x.Key.TreeId,
                x.Key.TierId,
                x.Average(y => y.Commission)))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you want this:

```
static IEnumerable<BuyerEarning> GetBuyer(bool acceptedOnly)
{
    var collectTo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).DayEnd();
    var collectFrom = collectTo.AddDays(-29).DayStart();

    using (var uow = new UnitOfWork(ConnectionString.PaydayLenders))
    {
        var r = new Repository<MatchHistory>(uow.Context);
        IQueryable<MatchHistory> results = r.Find()
            .Where(x =>
                x.CreatedOn <= collectTo &&
                x.CreatedOn >= collectFrom);

        if (acceptedOnly)
        {
            results = results
                .Where(x => x.ResultTypeId == (int)MatchResultType.Accepted);
        }

        return results
            .GroupBy(x => new
            {
                x.BuyerId,
                x.TreeId,
                x.TierId
            })
            .ToList()
            .Select(x => new BuyerEarning(
                x.Key.BuyerId,
                x.Key.TreeId,
                x.Key.TierId,
                x.Average(y => y.Commission)))
            .ToList();
    }
}
```